# Neo4j cypher complicated query sort ,count, sum before collect

Tags: sorting, neo4j, cypher, collect

I am newbie with neo4j db and just started learning it, looking for some help, because I am stuck. Is it possible to get it in one cypher query? how?

my graph structure looks like that:

```
(s:Store)-[r:RELEASED]->(m:Movie)<-[r1:ASSIGNED]-(cat:MovieCategorie)
```

How I could get this data?

- Movie store (got)
- Movie (got)
- Most common 5 categories of movies in that store (**I don't know how to sort them before using collect(cat.name)[0..5]**)

Anyone could suggest how to get this data? I tried lots of times and failed, this is what I got and it doesn't work.

```
match (s:Store) 
with s
match (s)-[r:RELEASED]->(m:Movie)
with s,m 
match (m)<-[r1:ASSIGNED]-(cat:MovieCategorie)
with s, m, count(r1) as stylesCount, cat
order by stylesCount
return distinct s as store, collect(cat.name)[0..5] as topCategories
order by store.name
```

Thank you!

---

Ok, so as I got my query right and I am developing this query further, got some problem by combining multiple aggregation functions COUNT and SUM.

My query witch works well for finding top 5 categories per store:

```
MATCH (s:Store)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:RELEASED]->(m:Movie)<-[r:ASSIGNED]-(cat:MovieCategorie)
WITH s, COUNT(r) AS count, cat
ORDER BY  count DESC
RETURN c AS Store, COLLECT(distinct cat.name) AS `Top Categories`
ORDER BY Store.name
```

On top of this query I need count how much views this store has sum(m.viewsCount) as Total store views. I tried to add in to same WITH statement as COUNT is, and tried to put it in return, In both scenarios it doesn't work how I would like to. Any suggestions, examples? I am still confused how WITH with aggregation functions works... :(

create example database

```
CREATE (s1:Store) SET s1.name = 'Store 1'
CREATE (s2:Store) SET s2.name = 'Store 2'
CREATE (s3:Store) SET s3.name = 'Store 3'

CREATE (m1:Movie) SET m1.title = 'Movie 1', m1.viewsCount = 50
CREATE (m2:Movie) SET m2.title = 'Movie 2', m2.viewsCount = 50
CREATE (m3:Movie) SET m3.title = 'Movie 3', m3.viewsCount = 50
CREATE (m4:Movie) SET m4.title = 'Movie 4', m4.viewsCount = 50
CREATE (m5:Movie) SET m5.title = 'Movie 5', m5.viewsCount = 50

CREATE (c1:MovieCategorie) SET c1.name = 'Cat 1'
CREATE (c2:MovieCategorie) SET c2.name = 'Cat 2'
CREATE (c3:MovieCategorie) SET c3.name = 'Cat 3'

CREATE (m1)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(c1)
CREATE (m1)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(c3)
CREATE (m2)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(c2)
CREATE (m3)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(c1)
CREATE (m3)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(c2)
CREATE (m3)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(c3)
CREATE (m4)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(c1)
CREATE (m4)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(c3)
CREATE (m5)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(c3)

CREATE (s1)-[:RELEASED]->(m1)
CREATE (s1)-[:RELEASED]->(m3)
CREATE (s1)-[:RELEASED]->(m4)
CREATE (s1)-[:RELEASED]->(m5)

CREATE (s2)-[:RELEASED]->(m1)
CREATE (s2)-[:RELEASED]->(m2)
CREATE (s2)-[:RELEASED]->(m3)
CREATE (s2)-[:RELEASED]->(m4)
CREATE (s2)-[:RELEASED]->(m5)

CREATE (s3)-[:RELEASED]->(m1)
```

---

SOLVED!! FINALLY I DID IT! Trick was use one more match after everything , great - now I can sleep in peace. Thank you.

```
MATCH (s:Store)-[:RELEASED]->(m:Movie)<-[r:ASSIGNED]-(cat:MovieCategorie)
with  s,count(r) as catCount,  cat
order by catCount desc
with s, collect( distinct cat.name)[0..5] as TopCategories
match (s)-[:RELEASED]->(m:Movie)
return s as Store, TopCategories, sum(m.viewsCount) as TotalViews
```

Comment: You should provide some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Regardless, I've answered your second question.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, that was fast :D I finally got it!

```
match (s:Store) 
with s
match (s)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(m:Movie)
with s
match (s)<-[r2:ASSIGNED]-(cat:MovieCategorie)
with s, count(r2) as stylesCount, cat
order by stylesCount desc
return distinct s,  collect(distinct cat.name)[0..5] as topCategories
order by s.name
```

So trick is first count() in with , then order by that with, and collect **DISTINCT** in return. I am not so sure about these mutiple with statements, will try to clean it up. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
MATCH (s:Store)-[:RELEASED]->(:Movie)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(cat:MovieCategorie)
WITH s, COUNT(cat) AS count, cat
ORDER BY s.name, count DESC
RETURN s.name AS Store, COLLECT(cat.name)[0..5] AS `Top Categories`
```

And if you want the sum of the `viewsCount` property from the Movie nodes per store:

```
MATCH (s:Store)-[:RELEASED]->(m:Movie)<-[:ASSIGNED]-(cat:MovieCategorie)
WITH s, COUNT(cat) AS count, m, cat
ORDER BY s.name, count DESC
RETURN s.name AS Store, COLLECT(cat.name)[0..5] AS `Top Categories`, SUM(m.viewsCount) AS `Total Views`
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but if I am passing m in with statement my categories are not sorted anymore and sum result is wrong for all the stores. I can't understand why?

Comment: I get the correct categories and sum results with the sample dataset I have created. You should share sample data.

Comment: I am added sample data, just tested your nice query with it and it says Store 3 100 views , when store3 has just one movie (each movie has 50 views). May you have any ideas why?

Comment: Oh there are overlapping categories. I'll get back to you when I'm at a computer.